# SQL query on join table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join

I've the follow SQL schema:

```
+----------+
| products |
+----------+
| id       |
| name     |
+----------+
    ^ 8
    |
    v 1
+-------------+
|   values    |
+-------------+
| value       |
| product_id  |
| property_id |
+-------------+
    ^ 8
    |
    v 1
+------------+
| properties |
+------------+
| id         |
| name       |
+------------+
```

One product has many properties and a property belongs to many products. The `values` table is the join table for the many_to_many association between `products` and `properties`. And in this table is saved the value of the property for a product.

Now I'm looking for a query to select all products with property `x` with value `a`, and property `y` with value `b` ecc. My try is this query but return no records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    products.* 
FROM 
    products 
INNER JOIN 
    product_values 
    ON product_values.product_id = products.id 
INNER JOIN 
    properties 
    ON properties.id = product_values.property_id 
WHERE 
    (properties.name = 'size' AND product_values.value = 'big') 
    AND (properties.name = 'color' AND product_values.value = 'red')
```

If possible I need a query with no nested select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a property can not be `color` and `size` at the same time you need to use `OR` in your `where` clause. Then group the data and check if both are in the group with  `having`

```
SELECT products.id, products.name
FROM `products` 
INNER JOIN `product_values` ON `product_values`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `properties` ON `properties`.`id` = `product_values`.`property_id` 
WHERE (properties.name = 'size' AND product_values.value = 'big') 
   OR (properties.name = 'color' AND product_values.value = 'red')
GROUP BY products.id, products.name
HAVING count(distinct properties.name) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select pv.product_id
from product_values pv join
     properties p
     on pv.property_id = p.id
where (p.name, v.value) in ( ('size', 'big'), ('color', 'red') )
group by pv.product_id
having count(distinct p.name) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `sum` to filter multiple attributes for an entity

```
SELECT  
  `p`.* 
FROM
  `products` p
  INNER JOIN `product_values` v
    ON `v`.`product_id` = `p`.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `properties`  pr
    ON `pr`.`id` = `v`.`property_id` 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM (pr.name = 'size' AND v.value = 'big') 
  AND SUM(pr.name = 'color' AND v.value = 'red')
```